# Second Cohomology group with a non-trivial action

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$ be the second cohomology group which corresponds to the trivial $G$ action. Then there are known methods for computing $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$ for $G$ a direct product or semi-direct products of abelian groups. For example for $G=C_4\times C_4$ it is fairly easy to show that $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)\cong C_4$ and for $G=S_3$ we have $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$ is trivial.

My problem is when $G$ acts in a non-trivial way, here e.g. by complex conjugation. Denoting this non-trivial action by $\eta$ I want to know how to compute $H^2_{\eta}(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$ for $G$ a direct product or semi-direct products of abelian groups. In particular I want to calculate $H^2_{\eta}(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$ for $G=C_4\times C_4$ and for $G=S_3$. My intuition says that the former is $C_4\times C_2$ and the latter $C_2$. The former "comes from" the commutator relation between the generators of $C_4\times C_4$ and from the $H^2_{\eta}(C_4,\mathbb{C}^*)$ and the latter is inflated from $H^2_{\eta}(C_2,\mathbb{C}^*)$. But these are more guesses than anything else.

I like to ask for your help, first if I am right and second how do I prove this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$0 \to \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{\cdot 2\pi i} \Bbb C \xrightarrow{\exp} \Bbb C^* \to 1$$

Where $G$ acts via inversion on $\Bbb Z$ and via complex conjugation on $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C^*$. We will always keep these action in mind and not explicitly express them in notation.

This induces an exact sequence on cohomology groups

$H^2(G,\Bbb C) \to H^2(G,\Bbb C^*) \to H^3(G,\Bbb Z) \to H^3(G,\Bbb C)$

Now complex conjugation being $\Bbb R$-linear, $\Bbb C$ is a $\Bbb R$-linear group representation of $G$ here. Using some homological algebra, group cohomology for $\Bbb R[G]$-modules $V$ can be computed as $\operatorname{Ext}^n_{\Bbb R[G]}(\Bbb R,V)$ or as $\operatorname{Ext}^n_{\Bbb Z[G]}(\Bbb Z,V)$, these yield the same result. But due to Maschke's theorem, the category $\Bbb R[G]\textrm{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ is semisimple, so these Ext-groups vanish.

Thus we actually get $H^2(G,\Bbb C^*) \cong H^3(G,\Bbb Z)$. Now the cohomology of $S_3$ is known to be $4$-periodic (this is an exercise in Brown's book on group cohomology iirc), so we get $H^3(G,\Bbb Z)=\hat{H}^{-1}(G,\Bbb Z)$. What is the norm map? We get for $k \in \Bbb Z$ that $N(k)=k+k+k-k-k-k=0$. Thus $\hat{H}^{-1}(G,\Bbb Z)=H_0(S_3,\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

To compute $H^3(C_4 \times C_4,\Bbb Z)$, we can use the [Künneth formula for nontrivial actions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75472/117693). I'll assume for an example calculation that the first factor acts trivially and the latter via complex conjugation. We just need to compute $H^3_\eta(C_4,\Bbb Z)$ (with the $\eta$ indicating the nontrivial coefficient action). $H^3_\eta(C_4,\Bbb Z)\cong \hat{H}^{-1}_\eta(C_4,\Bbb Z) \cong H_{0,\eta}(C_4,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ via a similar computation of norm and coinvariants as before. We also get $H^2_\eta(C_4,\Bbb Z)=\hat{H}^0_\eta(C_4,\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z^{C_4}=0$. Of course the cohomology of $C_4$ with trivial action on $\Bbb Z$ is well-known.

Putting this into the Künneth formula, we obtain the following, where I drop the $\Bbb Z$ and just write $\eta$ for the twisted coefficients and no subscript for trivial coefficients $$H^3(C_4)\otimes H^0_\eta(C_4)\oplus H^2(C_4)\otimes H^1_\eta(C_4)\oplus H^1(C_4)\otimes H^2_\eta(C_4)\oplus H^0(C_4)\otimes H^3_\eta(C_4)=\\(0\otimes 0)\oplus (\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \otimes \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\oplus (0 \otimes 0)\oplus (\Bbb Z\otimes \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$$
This is just the first term of the Künneth formula, for the second one, we obtain:

$$\operatorname{Tor}(H^4(C_4),H^0_\eta(C_4))
\oplus\operatorname{Tor}(H^3(C_4),H^1_\eta(C_4))
\oplus\operatorname{Tor}(H^2(C_4),H^2_\eta(C_4))
\oplus\operatorname{Tor}(H^1(C_4),H^3_\eta(C_4))
\oplus\operatorname{Tor}(H^0(C_4),H^4_\eta(C_4))$$

Because $H^k(C_4)$ vanishes for odd $k$ and $H^k_\eta(C_4)$ vanishes for even $k$, these summands are all zero.

Thus we get, unless I am mistaken that $H^2(C_4 \times C_4,\Bbb C^*)=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I need some time with Brown book to see if I understand it. I was not aware of a Künneth formula for nontrivial action.